# Rails controller design pattern idea for decreasing it's size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns

The question is what do you think about this pattern?

Problem:
You've got controller with index action, and this action is huge.
Action is full of ActiveRecord chaining and maybe some computations with records.
When you are adding new methods controller is getting bigger.

I've heard about "skinny controller fat model", and I'm just what? My models are already fat, are you crazy?

I've heard about service objects, they are not very usable as for me.

```
result = SomeService.new(params, request, flash, current_user).call
```

After such service object you could try:

```
result = SomeService.new(controller).call
# or
result = SomeService.new.(controller)
```

And what to do with returning error statutes from that service? As answered below, exceptions.
So, you need to create exceptions class, throw it, catch it and only then render something or make redirect.

Here is the pattern from subject:

```
# controllers/some_controller.rb
class SomeController < OtherController
  before_actions

  include Index
  include Show

  def create_update_and_destroy
    # small methods have no reason to leave controller
  end

  private

  def common_private_method
  end
end

# controllers/some_controller/index.rb
module SomeController::Index
  def index
    # code here
  end

  private

  def index_do_some_stuff
    # this method is prefixed by "index" to avoid name collision
  end
end
```

Yes, there is some_controller.rb and some_controller directory with actions as files.

Nobody in OOP likes prefixes and if your method has well explaining not short name - prefix is not necessary.

In my opinion, this is the most simple and obvious way. Just take fat code and split to modules!
What do you think?

Explainations about why I have many code:

In one project I have view, it requires records from several models, some related, some not related.

So I had started to write many scopes in models, time passed, I realized that this is wrong approach.

Different actions required very specific records selections, only action should know about such specifics. And I had scopes named "for_index", "for_show".

Now I'm creating module Index with metod index, and all record fetching and computing code is splitted into private methods right in place.

In other project I have API. Specific endpoint is returning specific deep nested json, several models are fetching. I already know that creating scopes in model for one specific endpoint is bad idea, so I'm splitting code amoung private methods. One action and five private methods for it. And next five public methods and 25 private? In single controller?

Comment: Without knowing why your controllers and models are fat it's hard to comment. Maybe you should ask individual questions about your controllers and models in more detail. I can say your description of service objects doesn't seem right. For example, you wouldn't pass a controller in. This may be why you have so much model and controller code. [This answer over here may help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52526676/14660). As for "returning error statutes from that service", those should be raised as exceptions.

Comment: I will say that breaking up your controller into a module per action sounds like a band-aid for a larger design problem. The question I'd ask is how much of that code in the controller is about controlling the view, and how much is doing work (ie. belongs in a service or model)? How much can be moved into [Helper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html), [Concerns](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html), and [Decorators](https://github.com/drapergem/draper)?

Answer (score 1):

Combining `form objects` with `service objects` and other patterns can make your model and controller thin. You can also add an `ActiveResource::Errors` object in your service object to collect errors.

Here's an example using user's input. Customize it according to your specification

```
class ProductForm
  ...
  def save
    if service_object.call
      self
    else
      append_errors(service_object)
      false
    end
  end

  def service_object
    @service_object ||= ProductCreationService.new(params)
  end

  def append_errors object
    errors.append object.errors # just for simplicity
  end
end
```

In your controller

```
def create
  @product = ProductForm.new params
  if @product.save
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

Controller actions should be straight forward and as short as possible. Complexities inside these actions can be lessen with other design patterns.

Actions that collects data can be abstracted by using `query`/`finder` objects.

Here's a rough example

```
class DashboardQuery
  attr_reader :options
  def initalize(options = {})
    @options = options
  end

  def branches
    @branches ||= Branch.all
  end

  def branch_count
    @branch_count ||= branches.count
  end
end

# Usage
@dashboard = DashboardQuery.new(params)
@dashboard.branch_count
@dashabord.branches
```